# Changing am/pm time to Unix MySQL And Concatenate 3 columns into 1 colum

Tags: mysql, database, concatenation, database-migration

So I'm working on migrating a database that has been created for keeping track of times and dates.  The way that these were stored can be a little wonky from database to database (I was not the original author so I'm not sure of the reasoning for storing the information in the way that the person did, but I'm sure they had their reasons).

So the first issue I have is that I have to merge three columns into one column for over 6000 rows of data, while also converting it to UNIX time.  I've googled and searched around the Internet and can't find a good set of documentation explaining how to do this.

I finally was able to get the columns to concatenate by using

```
SELECT CONCAT(startHour,':',startMinute, ' ', startTime) AS startingTime FROM events;
```

But I haven't been able to get the time to successfully go to unix time.  I also haven't been able to use that when dynamically inserting the concatenated rows into another db.

Here is the SUDO code (meaning I've changed table names and column names slightly).

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`id`, `label`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `startTime`, `endTime`)
    SELECT `id`, `tag`, CONCAT(startHour,':',startMinute, ' ', startTime) AS startingTime, CONCAT(endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime) AS endingTime
        FROM `oldTable`;
```

Also having an issue with NULL, NULL times still get converted, event though the conversion isn't a correct time.

## Update

This is what pulls from the DB when using the concat

```
SELECT CONCAT(startHour,':',startMinute, ' ', startTime) AS startingTime FROM events LIMIT 10;

+--------------+
| startingTime |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
| NULL         |
| NULL         |
| NULL         |
| NULL         |
| 8:0 am       |
| 8:0 am       |
| 8:0 am       |
| 8:0 am       |
| 1:0 pm       |
+--------------+
```

### UPDATE 2

I was able to get some proper 24:00 time formatting using this, but still can't get it to format into Unix time.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime)) AS endingTime
```

### UPDATE 3

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('Apr 13 1980 ', endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime),'%M %d %Y %h:%i%p') AS endingTime

+---------------------+
| endingTime          |
+---------------------+
| NULL                |
| NULL                |
| NULL                |
| NULL                |
| NULL                |
| 1980-04-13 17:00:00 |
| 1980-04-13 17:00:00 |
| 1980-04-13 17:00:00 |
| 1980-04-13 17:00:00 |
| 1980-04-13 17:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

I had some luck with this, but it doesn't format the time correctly.  The unix timestamp is off, it keeps giving me the time as 12:00.  Instead of 5:00pm as it is supposed to, but he str to time is reporting the correct 24 hour time.

### Update 4

The time appears off every time I convert something to UNIX_Timestamp and I'm not quite sure why.  Is there anything to do with timezone correction that could be causing this?

Just to test my hypothesis I did an example I found on [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).  The website shows a simple way to create a UNIX_TIMESTAMP

**The documentation code and result**

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-27 03:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-27 03:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                            1111885200 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

**My code and Result**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-27 03:00:00');
//in mysql Yeilds this timestamp 1111892400
// in php Sat, 26 Mar 2005 22:00:00 -0500
```

### UPDATE 5 (FINAL UPDATE)

I couldn't afford the time in trying to figure out a solid answer on formatting correct times through mysql, so I created a migration script using PHP that is manually run once. It made a nice way to grab the data, format it, and insert it into the new tables.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "UNIX time"? Are you referring to a UNIX_TIMESTAMP instead? That would be not only the hh:mm:ss, but it would also be the date as well. What is the desired format of the time that you want?

If you run this, does this give you the result you want:`TIME(CONCAT(endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime))`

Is the field that you're inserting into a time field?

**UPDATE**

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ',endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime))
```

Comment: No I'm inserting into a 11 digit int for a unix timestamp, this is so that later it can be used in some PHP that has already been developed. It also doesn't format correctly from time because of am pm issues.

Comment: I can use CURDATE for the date because it won't matter, I'll I'm concerned with is the time from it.

Comment: I updated the answer, try that and see if that gets you the result you were looking for.

Comment: That returns an error of an incorrect datetime value.  It can't directly format the 5:0pm

Comment: I've been playing with STR_TO_DATE with no luck 

```SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT(CURDATE() "," STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(endHour,':',endMinute, ' ', endTime),'%h:%i%p'))) AS endingTime FROM events LIMIT 10;```

Comment: I've added an update above that showcases the luck I had with str to date but it doesn't quite format correctly into unix time.

Comment: The server interprets date as a value in the current time zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC. That's why you're seeing a difference, I got this for example `1111910400`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hatem, I have adjusted my question to have the solution that worked for my situation.